# twitter bootstrap button background cut off in ie

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

good Day

I am using twitter bootstrap. Now the buttons display fine in ALL browsers except in IE9: The background of the button gets cut off right below the text. But in IE 10, the background shows fine (Also dine in IE7,8, but those buttons do not have rounded corners as in IE9 and 10).

any suggestions?

I am using the HTML 5 doctype as specified in Bootstrap, and no fun ny css or any other tags in my header....

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding HTML 5 fix for IE 9 :

```
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```